# Exceptions not been catched on Camel Spring DSL

Tags: spring, exception, apache-camel

I'm using a Camel route to transform a csv file into XML, using Spring DSL. I use JAXB with an annotated class and an .xsd to validate the result.

At the route, I use a doTry/doCatch block of code. If any exception occurs, I write the actual message to a file. I also use a custom process to fransform a CSV file into a instance of my annotated class. My problem is as follows:
If for example, I change a name in the .xsd file, an exception is thrown and in the route, the doCatch snippet is executed and the message is writted to a file. But if an exception is thrown at my processor, the doCatch is ignored.

```
<route>
    <from uri="file://C:/a"/>   


        <doTry>     
        <unmarshal><csv delimiter=","/></unmarshal>
        <process ref="myProccesor"/>
        <marshal ref="jb"></marshal>
        <to uri="file://C:/ok"/> 
        <doCatch>
            <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
            <to uri="file://C:/nok"/>
        </doCatch>
    </doTry>
  </route>
```

Comment: SO, how is anyone supposed to help without seeing how your code is?

Comment: The exceptions thown by myProcessor are not catched by the doCatch statement.

Comment: What kind of exception is thrown? Try to catch java.lang.Throwable to see what happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you shure, doCatch is ignored? It should catch your exception, but you must tell camel that exception is handled. Without this camel won't catch it. After `<exception></exception>` add

```
<handled>
    <constant>true</constant>
</handled>
```